Microsoft Azure Storage
Quiero saber como implementar el apartado de "Retrying failures" en laravel del paquete de Microsoft Azure Storage, para que cuando falle la subida de un archivo lo vuelva a reintentar, se supone que en el repositorio esta la forma pero no se exactamente como implementarlo en laravel
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php?tab=readme-ov-file#retrying-failures
este es el repositorio

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
